# Know how many are waiting on a pthread mutex lock

Tags: multithreading, locking, pthreads

I would like to know how many threads are waiting on a lock so I would be able to destroy it safely.

The problem is that I can't destroy the lock when someone holds it or someone is waiting on it.
My program can make sure that no new requests are made to acquire the lock, but how can I know when all the threads that waited on it are done with it?

I thought about a conditional variable but I suspect it will create problems..

Comment: You're shagged.  Any such info, even if available, is stale by the time you get it.  Change your design so that such info. is not required.

Answer (score 0):

dlv, could you add some code snippet to your description.
I hope you should be using condition variables,

Each thread will block in `pthread_cond_wait()` until the other thread signals it to wake up. This will not cause a deadlock. It can easily be extended to many threads, by allocating one `int`, `pthread_cond_t` and `pthread_mutex_t` per thread.

`pthread_cond_wait()` blocks the calling thread until the specified condition is signalled. This routine should be called while mutex is locked, and it will automatically release the mutex while it waits. After signal is received and thread is awakened, mutex will be automatically locked for use by the thread. The programmer is then responsible for unlocking mutex when the thread is finished with it.

The `pthread_cond_signal()` routine is used to signal (or wake up) another thread which is waiting on the condition variable. It should be called after mutex is locked, and must unlock mutex in order for `pthread_cond_wait()` routine to complete.

The `pthread_cond_broadcast()` routine should be used instead of pthread_cond_signal() if more than one thread is in a blocking wait state.

It is a logical error to call `pthread_cond_signal()` before calling `pthread_cond_wait()`.

Proper locking and unlocking of the associated mutex variable is essential when using these routines. For example:
Failing to lock the mutex before calling `pthread_cond_wait()` may cause it NOT to block.
Failing to unlock the mutex after calling `pthread_cond_signal()` may not allow a matching `pthread_cond_wait()` routine to complete (it will remain blocked).

Answer (score 0):

If threads that can use the mutex still exist or might be created in the future then don't delete it.

You do know and are tracking what threads are created, right?

If, for some reason, you cannot keep track of the threads using a resource, your only way out is to leak the resource. It can never be safely deleted because you never know when you are done using it.

Say you had a counter that counted the threads using a mutex. That counter would need its own mutex. Then how do you decide when to delete that one?

Answer (score 0):

That way of thinking is the road that leads to hell. You could do what you want with condition variables, but the result would be an extremely weak design.

Assuming you managed to create such a monster, it would basically allow you to kill "safely" any other thread regardless of its internal state. Except for a quick and dirty panic exit (in case of some internal software error), this is the worst possible way of solving synchronization issues.

A design relying on such tricks would have to create implicit synchronizations between tasks to make sure the terminations occur in the proper order. A lot of software are designed that way, and most of them allow mediocre programmers to make a living by maintaining the pile of crap they created in the first place.

Task termination should be an issue solved at global design level, not by a toolbox of wonky objects that allow you to twist synchronization any odd way.